# Prevent Screen Wake / Activity from Android Timer

Tags: lock-screens, clock

I've got an android timer running through the base clock in android 11 (oneplus 7t).

**EDIT**: It appears I'm wrong. This is the oneplus clock, not the base android clock. Why they would bother replacing that is an entirely different question of stupidity.

Every few minutes it lights up the screen to let me know the progress of the timer. This is the most useless and dumb features I've seen in a long time. I cannot find any way to turn it off.

To reproduce, go into clock > timer > set one for say thirty minutes. Lock screen. Watch screen illuminate and wake in a process of infinite stupid.

Please help, this is annoying as all hell. I need to have my screen visible in case I receive an important message etc, but I don't want this thing stealing my attention every few minutes.

Comment: No repro on Pixel 3a running Android 11 with the default [Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.deskclock) app. The behavior may depend on the Clock app, and OnePlus might customize their own Clock app. Try different 3rd-party Clock/Timer app instead.

Comment: Well damn, you are right, it appears to be a oneplus app disaster!